# how to retrieve perspective transformation parameters from homography transformation matrix

Tags: matrix, transformation, perspective, homography

In Proposed method, homography transformation parameters matrix are found based on feature matching points which are found using SIFT/SURF/ORB method.
H(homography matrix) = |   a     b      p |
                       |   c     d      q |
                       |   m    n      s |

where a, b, c and d elements are for scaling, rotation, reflection and shearing. m and n elements for translation. s for scaling. p and q are projection elements.

I have used [Reference image 0000000.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLUam.jpg)
 and [Sense image 0000001.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbxsQ.jpg).   From those images, I have found matching corresponding points using SURF and found homography matrix as:
1.1777      -0.003198      -57.0282
0.0250       1.14970       -103.581
0.00000578  -0.0000011      1

From Dataset has given intrinsic and extrinsic parameters of data. 
Intrinsic Camera K matrix values are: "k11 k12 k13 k21 k22 k23 k31 k32 k33 focal-length radial-distortion1, radial-distortion2. Extrinsic [R t] matrix are as: r11 r12 r13 r21 r22 r23 r31 r32 r33 t1 t2 t3".

If Z is not present then  r31, r32 and r33 are zero.

Homography geometry is used when t1 t2 and t3 are zero, otherwise that geometry is consider as epipolar geometry.

The projection matrix for that image is K*[R t]. The rotation and translation is based on the right-handed coordinate system. We are consider homography geometry. So, projection matrix H=KR(K)-1(it is based on different survey papers).

Internal parameters of camera matrix(3x3) K=
1606.293463      0.000             536.000000
0.000            1606.293463       356.000000
0.000            0.000             1.000

Rotation matrix(3x3) is R=
0.882736      -0.043816     -0.467823
0.040970       0.999028     -0.016262
0.468080      -0.004811      0.883673

So, based on this equation, H(homogrphy projection trasnformation matrix)H=KR(K)-1=
1.03893     -0.04542    ***-818.50793***
0.14471      0.99796    ***-144.37276***
0.00029     -0.00000     0.72855

My questions are as:
1) Why these bold values of matrix(p and q parameters of homography matrix) are not matched with proposed matrix value?

2) how to compare my method's transformation parameters with dataset's transformation parameters?

Thank you,